# "Class implemented in both" & "API key not valid" errors when registering a user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm building a chat app and exploring with Cocoapods and Firebase. I need to register a user and need to segue the register screen onto a chat screen.

I've added code to make the titleLabel look like it's being typed. The animation works overall, but when it runs I get all these "Implemented in both" errors in the debug console. (see below)

Once I advance onto the register screen from the WelcomeViewController, and I input info to register a new user, I expect the RegisterViewController to segue into the ChatViewController (I've added an image for reference).

I have tried cleaning the project, made sure pods and Firebase are all updated, restarted, etc.

This is my RegisterViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextfield: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func registerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
                if let e = error {
                    print(e)
                } else {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegisterToChat", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

As mentioned, the other issue is that the segue is not working and shows the following errors:

```
"Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999" 

"code = 400;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.";
            reason = badRequest;
        }
```

Really confused about this API error. What am I missing here?

Below are the errors that show up:

```
objc[74482]: Class CSAudioFileManager is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x1312ad210) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x130189990). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74482]: Class CSAudioFileReader is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x1312ad1c0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x130189c10). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74482]: Class CSAudioTimeConverter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x1312addf0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13018a7f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74482]: Class SSRAESKeyManager is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x1312ae728) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13018a868). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74482]: Class CSPlainAudioFileWriter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x1312ad0d0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13018a9d0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74482]: Class CSAudioChunkForTV is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x1312ad080) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13018aa70). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74482]: Class CSVoiceTriggerEventInfoProvider is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x1312adf30) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13018b380). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2020-10-07 22:45:38.348599-0400 Flash Chat iOS13[74482:8785502] [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.thebluetheory.Flash-Chat-iOS13 due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled
2020-10-07 22:45:38.348871-0400 Flash Chat iOS13[74482:8785495] [KBDAnalyticsLog] -[TIAnalyticsService _registerEventSpec:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered.
2020-10-07 22:45:38.376869-0400 Flash Chat iOS13[74482:8785495] [KBDAnalyticsLog] -[TIAnalyticsService _registerEventSpec:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered.
2020-10-07 22:45:42.976841-0400 Flash Chat iOS13[74482:8785495] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed

Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600003c6f300 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 400;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.";
            reason = badRequest;
        }
    );
    message = "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.";
    status = "INVALID_ARGUMENT";
}}}}
```

[Register screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzSjQ.jpg)

Comment: Try to go to the auth section in the firebase console and enable the Email/password sign-in method and save. Again download the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file and add to your project

Comment: Thanks! The re-downloading GoogleService-Info.plist file worked for making the segue work. Though I'm still getting the following errors: 
"block_invoke TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered." 

and 

"nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed"

Comment: From the screenshot, I think you are following this example https://github.com/moazelshebly/FlashChat-iOS13. When I run code in Xcode 11.1 then there is no error as you said. Maybe you are using Xcode 12 and this issue may be with Xcode 12 simulator, try to check in the device

Comment: Help us to help you by doing some basic troubleshooting. The screenshot shown in the question has nothing to do with Firebase, nor does it reflect any code that's causing the error so not sure why it's there. Please step through your code line by line until it crashes, then include that section of the code in the question so we can take a look. Lastly, it's unclear if the Firebase Auth code in the question works or doesn't work or print's an error. Can you please update and clarify the question?